# R: Obtaining lsmeans for each row of data

Tags: r, lsmeans

I am currently attempting to use lsmeans on a negative binomial model to obtain least squared means for each participant in my dataset. I am able to ascertain lsmeans by my exposure of interest, but not adjusted means for each participant. My code thus far is posted below:

```
library(MASS)
library(lsmeans)

m1 <- zeroinfl(exposure ~ BMI_Category,
           data = data_final, dist = "negbin", EM = TRUE)
summary(m1)

lsBact <- lsmeans(m1, specs = "BMI_Category")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: LS means summarize a model — not a dataset. And your model has only the one predictor. I don’t see a predictor for participants in the model. If a participant corresponds to an individual observation, then the question makes no sense — instead, perhaps you are asking for a prediction interval for each participant, and that’s a different animal altogether.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @rvl! I apologize for the confusion, I believe you are correct in stating that what I am looking for is a prediction of the exposure for each participant based on the covariate data I have for each participant. As an example: I may have data on diet, BMI Category, and Diabetes status, and I would like to predict the life expectancy for each participant, not just get the lsmeans. Should I simply use the predict function in R with my negative binomial model?

Comment: yes, I think that is what you need to do. You likely will only be able to get point predictions — not intervals around them, unless that is provided by the package you are using.